# How to use subquery to drop rows from Tab1 which are in Tab2 in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have tables in Oracle SQL like below:

Tab1

```
ID
-----
1
2
3
```

Tab2

```
ID
-----
3
4
5
```

And I need to take values from Tab1 which are not in Tab2. I made query like below:

```
select ID
from Tab1
where ID not in (select ID from Tab2)
```

Above query does not work, how can I change it to achieve result as I need:

```
ID
---
1
2
```

I can add that I prefere to use subquery in this problem, how can I do that in Oracle SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `MINUS` set operator:

```
SQL> with
  2  tab1 (id) as
  3    (select 1 from dual union all
  4     select 2 from dual union all
  5     select 3 from dual
  6    ),
  7  tab2 (id) as
  8    (select 3 from dual union all
  9     select 4 from dual union all
 10     select 5 from dual
 11    )
 12  select id from tab1
 13  minus
 14  select id from tab2;

        ID
----------
         1
         2

SQL>
```

---

BTW, query you used (with a subquery) returns correct result; did you mean to say that you prefer **NOT** to use a subquery?

```
 <snip>
 12  select id from tab1
 13  where id not in (select id from tab2);

        ID
----------
         1
         2
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it using subquery ?

Comment: Your query uses a subquery. What's wrong with it?

Comment: My query with subquery does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it worked fine :

select ID
from Table1
where ID not in (select ID from Table2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant **DROP** rows from a table, but you *can* **DELETE** them.

So correcting you title to

> How to use subquery to *DELETE* rows from Tab1 which are in Tab2 in Oracle SQL?

do so:

```
delete from tab1
where id  in (select id from tab2);

1 row deleted.

select * from tab1;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
```

Do not forget to `commit` to make the change *permanent*.